# how to Upload image before text

Tags: android

Adding `Checkboxes` and `RadioButton`s and aslo i want add image before text

please see in this   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
final CharSequence[] gender = {"Gmail","Facebook","Twitter","Exit"};
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailPage.this);
        alert.setTitle("Select Type");

        alert.setCancelable(false);

        alert.setSingleChoiceItems(gender,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                if(gender[which]=="Gmail")
                {
}
}
}
```

This is my Source code i want to add gmail ,facebook and twitter icon before its text can You

please tell me how i'll do this please post code according to my code i have tried much but

not able to understnd. Help me

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a Dialog with a custom view, check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) for more info.